# JavaScript to Typescript - anonymous computed

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

In a project I am trying to learn with, I have some working code:

```
ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.isUploading()) {
            ... Do something.
            });
        }
        else {
            ... Do something else
        }
    });
```

I'm now trying to convert my code to TypeScript, but ... am battling to convert this bit.

I am trying:

```
KnockoutComputed(() => {
    if (this.isUploading()) {
        ... do something.
        });
    } else  {
        ... do something else.
}
```

But I am being told "parameter type is expected".

What I am trying to do is execute some code when "this.isUploading()" changes value.

How should this be achieved in TypeScript?

Comment: You should still be calling `ko.computed`. Or really, just don't change anything at all. The JS code still behaves the same way, there's no need to change code arbitrarily.

Comment: I have tried that now, by just using the same code, but it says "expect ;" after the "ko".

Comment: take a look here - https://jsfiddle.net/ahLzcwu4/

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, what I had in my javascript, didn't assign anything to a variable. It was just a 'ko.computed'. Within the code, it made changes to things. In the example you've provided, the value is being assigned "this.myComputedVariable = ko.computed(()".  So for a 'computed', you need to return a value?

Comment: I don't think it is _compulsory_ for a `computedObservable` to always return a value. However, there has to be a dependency created on certain `observables` inside your `computedObservable` so that it can respond to the changes/updates in the `observables` it is dependent on.... For example, in my fiddle I shared previously, it is just an `alert` function that is called, but the `myComputedVariable` is not returning anything...

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with brackets. This should look like:

```
ko.computed(() => {
    if(this.isUploading()) {
        //... do something.
    } else  {
        //... do something else.
    }
});
```

I case if you want to compute some value:

```
var computedValue = ko.computed<any>(() => {
    var result: any; // some result
    if(this.isUploading()) {
        //... do something.
    } else  {
        //... do something else.
    }
    return result;
});
```

Note: change `any` to the certain type.

Comment: Thanks! In my javascript version, the computed never returned anything. It just did some stuff, and set a few variables. Is that not the right way to do things? It seems I MUST return a value?

Comment: It is not mandatory for computed to return any value. You can use computed to recalculate someth or do someth if you want to subscribe to a set of observables that you are using inside this computed.